# Having issue with Infura mainnet web3 connection and getting info

Tags: web3js, infura, web3-providers, websocket

I have been looking at a tutorial from [DappUniversity about Web3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3wM5903ty0&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgXlCGXNfzKdq7nGBcIaVOdN)... on the introductory video, I have completed all stages fine, but when getting to retriving account balance information from the mainnet ( i picked a random account from the Etherscan.io) it doesn't retrieve it.

I get an error like this when looking at the balance on its own  ---|>  `web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => { balance = bal })`
the respond is `'undefined'` and does not return a account value in Wei...

I tried getting to read the balance error through --|>  `web3.eth.getBalance(address)`

### that returns the following: >>>

```
> web3.eth.getBalance(address)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> (node:9060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\User\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:42:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\User\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:87:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\User\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\User\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\User\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
(node:9060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9060) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

---

what can i do to solve this issue!

Answer (score 1):

web3.eth.getBalance(address) returns a promise which will only either return an error or the balance once the transaction is mined.

> `function getBalance(){
>   var balance;
>   web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => { balance = bal })
>   return balance;
>   }`

the case above will return undefined because the function already returned the balance before the bal was retrieved and assigned to balance.

> `async function getBalance(){
>   var balance;
>   await web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => { balance = bal })
>   return balance;
>   }`

With regards to the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""` Does it occur while calling getBalance()? It might be helpful to post a more detailed code also to better help resolve this error.